# Using datetime2 to automatically update dates?

Tags: datetime2

I've been wondering if the following things are possible entirely within LaTeX using the datetime2 package (at the moment I'm using the python package and an external text file to create tables of dates using Python).

1) The first is to have a list of date ranges in the following manner. Given a specific start date, which might not be today, produce a set of date ranges covering successive weeks:

10-10-2016 --- 10-16-2016

10-17-2016 --- 10-23-2016 etc.

2) Producing a set of days of the week, say Monday, Wednesday, and Friday, for each of the ranges specified above. So something like

10-10-2016: Monday  Wednesday  Friday

10-17-2016: Monday  Wednesday Friday etc.

I do have a working version using Python, but it would be nice to have everything within LaTeX. I've played around with datetime2 but can't see a way to do this, and perhaps datetime2 is not the appropriate package for this. Any thoughts would be most welcome.

Comment: I think `pgfcalendar` might be best for that (if you want a LaTeX solution). I've got some examples in [Displaying a Calendar](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/displaycalendar.shtml) if you want to look at iterating over a set of dates. The `pgfcalendar` package is automatically loaded by `datetime2-calc` (or `\usepackage[calc]{datetime2}`) so you can use `\pgfcalendar` to produce the ranges and `datetime2` to format the dates.

Comment: I find the `datenumber` package very simple and useful, depending on what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks Nicola and Alan. I'll follow up on those suggestions.